# How to sum a std::list of various inherit classes C++?

Tags: c++, list, oop

Thank you first :(.
So i'm doing my homework right now, working with std::list and inherit classes.

I want to get the sum of objects in class A/B/C in a std::list Lists;

I'm trying for_each but maybe i was wrong.

My Classes

```
class Pets
{
protected:
    std::string iName;
    float iPrice;
public:
    virtual float getPrice();
    Pets();
    virtual ~Pets();
};

class Cat : public Pets
{
    std::string iType;
public:
    virtual float getPrice();
    Cat();
    virtual ~Cat();
};
class Dog : public Pets
{
    float iWeight;
public:
    virtual float getPrice();
    Dog();
    virtual ~Dog();
};
```

This is my Source.cpp

```
#include "Pets.h"
#include "Dog.h"
#include "Cat.h"
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

void main() {
    std::list<Pets*> List;
    float sum = 0;
    std::for_each(List.begin(), List.end(), sum = sum + std::mem_fun(&Pets::getPrice));
    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: Are you using C++11 or newer?

Comment: What error are you getting? (compilation error, output different from expected output, ...)

Comment: You never instantiate any `Pets` instance in your code. What do you expect?

Comment: I created instances in my code, but i deleted it when posting it here (for a shorter view)
Yes, i'm using C++14

Comment: Exactly, i don't know what to do to achieve my goal now, i want to sum the price, but i don't know how, this code have compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pets` doesn't have a member `getTien`. Did you mean to write `&Pets::getPrice`?

You can't just put an arbitrary expression as the third parameter of `std::for_each`. You need to supply either a function or an object with `operator()`, such as a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). A more specific algorithm for your use is [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

```
#include "Pets.h"
#include "Dog.h"
#include "Cat.h"
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

void main() {
    std::list<Pets*> List;
    auto addPrice = [](float acc, Pets * pet){ return acc + pet->getPrice(); };
    float sum = std::accumulate(List.begin(), List.end(), 0.0, addPrice);
    system("pause");   
}
```

Comment: Oh my bad, it was getPrice

Comment: I tried your code, and it turned out to be integer, not float as we expected.
But thank you, i will try my best, thank you.

Comment: @HaloNewWorld oops, fixed